# Checking element visibility in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, dom, element

I have been trying to find a way to determine if an element is visible in Angular without including full blown jQuery. The line I am struggling with is:

```
visibleElement = $('#detect-breakpoints .breakpoint:visible');
```

I have tried using various combinations of document.querySelector and document.querySelectorAll but nothing has worked.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to add this is using uibootstrap visible-* classes to show and hide divs.

Comment: short answer: you shouldn't. Angular wants you to rely on the model, the controller, which the DOM will reflect. If something is supposed to be hidden, you should have a `$scope.hideMyStuff` somewhere set to true

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use `angular.element` if you want to use jquery like element selectors. Something like:

```
$('#detect-breakpoints .breakpoint').is(':visible');
```

should also work.

But if you use the in-built directives `ng-hide`or `ng-show` to handle the visibility states of your elements in the angular app, then you won't need such selectors in because you could use the framework to achieve the same.